# Property of representations of reductive group schemes over characteristic 0 field

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, reductive-groups, group-schemes, groupoids

I originally posted this on [Maths SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3475758/property-of-representations-of-reductive-group-schemes-over-characteristic-0-fie), but then I thought it MO might be more fitting.

Let $k$ be a characteristic $0$ field and let $G$ be a linear algebraic group scheme over $k$. Then is it true that $G$ is reductive if and only if the category of representations of $G$, $\mathsf{Rep}(G)$ is semi-simple ?

P/s: $\mathsf{Rep}(\mathcal{G})$ is defined as the functor category $[\mathcal{G}, \mathcal{C}]$, where $\mathcal{G}$ is a groupoid and $\mathcal{C}$ is some category.

Comment: Theorem 22.42 (https://www.jmilne.org/math/Books/iag.html)

Comment: @Eoin Would you mind expanding on the relevance of this theorem ? My background in representation theory isn't particularly strong. Thank you.

Comment: Compare with 9.54. It answers your question in the affirmative.

Comment: @eoin Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer, as Eoin [pointed out](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/348363/property-of-representations-of-reductive-group-schemes-over-characteristic-0-fie#comment872534_348363), is yes. For those who use the pdf version of Milne's book [Algebraic groups](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/iAG200.pdf) available on his website, the theorem to look for is 22.138 (apparently there were enumeration changes during the publication process) on p. 424.

[image: screenshot of page 424]

Comment: It's good to have this as an answer, but it's probably polite first to ask [@Eoin](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/348363/property-of-representations-of-reductive-group-schemes-over-characteristic-0-fie#comment872534_348363) to post it rather than doing so immediately yourself.